# Launch program with specific env settings from cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

So, if using bash, I might do something like:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://my.proxy.com:8080 ./some_app
```

and the app would launch and use the proxy I've specified. Is there any way to do this kind of thing with CMD on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
 SET HTTP_PROXY=http://my.proxy.com:8080
 .\some_app
```